# How can I edit headers of e-mail in my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, email-headers

I used Thunderbird to move e-mails from one account into my Gmail account, but somehow some of the e-mails' *From* headers have disappeared. I would like to edit the e-mails to add these headers again.

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to be possible from within Gmail.

The only way I can think to do it is to use a third-party email client (like Thunderbird) to export the messages to text files, edit them, then re-import them back into the email client, then add them to the Gmail account.